# Working with google charts (want to get the value of column when click on the column)

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

I am working with Google charts. I want to get the value of column which is clicked. column name is showing in alert but I want get the percentage value also

```
 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('divAgingReport'));
        chart.draw(data2, options);

        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
            debugger;
            var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
            if (selectedItem) {
                var status = data2.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
               alert(status);
            }
        });
```

I am showing two images also:

[image]

want to show percentage value:

[image]

Comment: Please analyse selectedItem.row in console window. Use console.log(selectedItem.row) to view all the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use column index `1` to get the value...

label --> `data2.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);`

value --> `data2.getValue(selectedItem.row, 1);`